# Maths Conditional Statements Resulting All Affected Datagridview Cells the Same Colours

Tags: c#, math, datagridview, conditional-statements

I have a dataGridView which lists out a long list of prices, so my base price is `17.25`, if the value in `Cells[2]` of each `row` is 1.5% higher than `17.25`, highlight it as yellow; if the value in `Cells[2]` of each `row` is 3.0%, highlight it as orange. However, they are all highlighted in yellow even though there are values that supposed to fall into orange category.

How can I stop the yellow colour as soon as the value *supposed to* enters orange zone? Can anyone review/correct my code? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you! :)

```
private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double baseprice = 17.25;
    double onepoint5 = baseprice * 1.015;
    double threepoint0 = baseprice * 1.03;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_showPrices.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["Prices_Date"].Value.ToString() != "")
        {
            int cellprices = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[2].Value);
            if (cellprices >= onepoint5)
            {
                row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (cellprices >= threepoint0)
            {
                row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Two sample prices `17.50` and `17.75` that should be painted in yellow (`1.5%`) and orange (`3.0%`) respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your if-statement. If the value is bigger than `threepoint0`, it is **also** bigger than `onepoint5`, so the else-if never gets reached.

You have to check if the value lies **between** `onepoint5` and `threepoint0`.

Change into the following to fix your problem:

```
if (cellprices >= onepoint5 && cellprices < threepoint0)
{
       row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
else if (cellprices >= threepoint0)
{
       row.Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
}
else
{
       //do nothing
}
```

You are having a second problem and it is in this line: `int cellprices = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[2].Value);`.

Here, you are converting your value to an `integer`, which changes `17,50` to `18`. You have to convert to a double in order to compare two doubles: `Convert.ToDouble(value)`.

See example:

```
double firstValue = 17.50;

Console.WriteLine("double value:" + firstValue);
Console.WriteLine("integer value:" + Convert.ToInt16(firstValue));
Console.WriteLine("double converted value:" + Convert.ToDouble(firstValue));
Console.Read();
```

Output:

double value: 17,5
integer value: 18
double converted value: 17,5

To fix your issue, change this line: `int cellprices = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[2].Value);` into `double cellprices = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);`

Comment: Matthijs, I did try this but it ended up painted all in orange.

Comment: I've just added two sample prices in my original post. :)

Comment: Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: Sorry it was my fault using `int`! I tried the fix, this time around it paints only the `17.75` with yellow (supposed to be orange). `17.50` wasn't painted at all (supposed to be yellow).

Comment: I am getting that same result, let me check further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your continuous help :) I'm also working on it.

Comment: 17,50 shouldn't be yellow as onepoint 5 is 17,50875. So this outcome is correct. Issue resolved!

Comment: Matthijs, I'm truly sorry to confuse you. Yes, I tried to change the percentage to smaller percentage so that the two prices `17.50` and `17.75` can meet the conditions, and I can confirm now they are showing correct colours. Thank you very much for your time, really appreciate it a lot. Once again I apologise! :/